# How to replace second specific character in url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following url to work with:

...login?returnUrl=%2F%2Fprint?newdata=%test1234

I need to replace the second(last) ' ? ' by an ampersand

Please help..

Comment: How did it end up like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could;

```
url = url.replace(/\?([^\?]*)$/g, '&$1')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'your url';

//GET INDEX OF FIRST "?" CHARACTER
var index = url.indexOf("?");

//FIRST PART OF URL (BEFORE AND INCLUDING THE FIRST "?" CHARACTER)
var first_part = url.substring(0,(index+1));

//SECOND PART OF STRING (AFTER AND EXCLUDING THE FIRST "?" CHARACTER)
var second_part = url.substring((index+1), url.length);

//SECOND PART REPLACE "?" WITH "&"
var second_part_replace = second_part.replace("?","&");

//YOUR FINAL URL
var new_string = first_part+""+second_part_replace;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 0; 
str.replace(/\?/g, function () { return count++ == 0 ? '?' : '&'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parts = url.split('?');
url = parts.slice(0, parts.length - 2).join('?') +'&'+parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Using `slice`, `split` and `join` you can achieve that. Or using some regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (targets the second one) :

```
var url = 'login?returnUrl=%2F%2Fprint?newdata=%test1234';
var index = url.indexOf('?', url.indexOf('?') + 1);
if (index !== -1) url = url.slice(0, index) + '&' + url.slice(index + 1);
```

Or this (targets the last one) :

```
var url = 'login?returnUrl=%2F%2Fprint?newdata=%test1234';
url = url.replace(/\?(?=[^\?]*$)/, '&');
```